# Class 'Nuwave\Lighthouse\WhereConstraints\WhereConstraintsServiceProvider' not found

Tags: laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I just clone my project from Github, but then i run `composer install` I got error message

> In ProviderRepository.php line 208:
>
> Class 'Nuwave\Lighthouse\WhereConstraints\WhereConstraintsServiceProvider' not found

"laravel/framework": "5.7.*",
"nuwave/lighthouse": "^4.5",

Answer (score 1):

**I Already Solved My Issue**

I just remove the package.lock
Then remove also the vendors folder

From there i can run now the `composer install`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try in the console:

```
composer update
```

or

```
composer dump-autoload
```